# Configuring 1 to (1 or zero) relationship using EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entity-relationship

How do I configure the following relationship using

```
    EntityTypeConfiguration<Garden>
    EntityTypeConfiguration<House>
```

Garden to House

- A garden always has 1 house.
- Some houses have 1 garden, others have none.

I have already tried other posts and the documentation for [HasRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671317(v=vs.113).aspx), which says it configures a "required relationship", but does not explain what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using Data Annotations instead:

For your `Garden` class:

```
[Required, ForeignKey("House")]
public int HouseID { get; set; }

public virtual House House { get; set; }
```

For your `House` class:

```
[ForeignKey("Garden")]
public int? GardenID { get; set; }

public virtual Garden Garden { get; set; }
```

Comment: unfortunately I need to use  EntityTypeConfiguration<T>